# linear correlation formula and maximum using Copulas

Tags: correlation, random-variable, copula

I am currently working on linear correlation between two random variables functions (say cdf $F$ and $G$).

As far as I understand it is possible to correlate those random variables with copulas. For example we can work with a Gaussian correlation structure (we can note $\rho_1$ as the linear correlation used in the gaussian copula), this will give rvs with cdf F and G and linear correlation $\rho_2$.

Is there any formula between $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ ? How does this hold in n dimensions ?

I am currently playing with $\rho_1$ and see that $\rho_2$ is bounded. 
Using gaussian copulas, is there any bound for $\rho_2$ ? Does this hold for other copulas ? Does this hold in general ?

The last question is bothering me a bit more because I can't understand a case where we would have two perfectly correlated r.v. with different c.d.f.

Comment: Could you elaborate on these "bounds", given that *all* correlation coefficients must lie in the bounded interval $[-1,1]$?

Comment: I assume that the correlation of my rvs $\rho_2$ is increasing with $\rho_1$. (This is supported by simulations). As $\rho_1 = 1$ give numerical problem I work with $\rho_1=0.9999...$ This give $\rho_2 = 0.849$. For information I work with two lognormal ( with parameters (10,1.5) and (12,2.5)).